# mongodb aggregate apply a function to a field

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

As part of an aggregate I need to run this transformation:

```
  let inheritances = await db.collection('inheritance').aggregate([ 
    { $match: { status: 1 }}, // inheritance active
    { $project: { "_id":1, "name": 1, "time_trigger": 1, "signers": 1, "tree": 1, "creatorId": 1, "redeem": 1, "p2sh": 1 } },
    { $lookup:
      {
        from: "user",
        let: { creatorId: { $concat: [ "secretkey", { $toString: "$creatorId" } ] }, time_trigger: "$time_trigger"},
        pipeline: [
          { $match:
            { $expr:  
              { $and:
                [
                  { $eq: [ "$_id", sha256( { $toString: "$$creatorId" } ) ] },
                  { $gt: [ new Date(), { $add: [ { $multiply: [ "$$time_trigger", 24*60*60*1000 ] }, "$last_access" ] } ] }, 
                ]
              }
            }
          },
        ],
        as: "user"
      }, 
    },
    { $unwind: "$user" }
  ]).toArray()
```

creatorId comes from a lookup, and in order to compare it to _id I first need to do a sha256.

How can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: it would be better if you can provide sample docs & that should be enough but just in case you can provide required o/p as well.

Comment: I added the whole function. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

External functions will not work with the aggregation framework. Everything is parsed to BSON by default. It is all basically processed from BSON operators to native C++ code implementation, This is by design for performance.

Basically in short, you can't do this. I recommend just storing the hashed value on every document as a new field, otherwise you'll have to do it in code just before the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks. What a pity. Storing the hashed value is precisely what I'm trying to avoid.